# Normal Derivative times Partial Derivative Expansion

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

[image: Section from a derivation for Euler-Lagrange Equation]

[^Section from a derivation for Euler-Lagrange Equation]

Just a short question. I'm unable to make sense of the equality in Eq'n 4. Is a rule/law being applied here? If not, can someone expand on the intermediatory steps?

Thank you

Comment: Its the product rule.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks.
I feel so dumb.